# I open the Meerkat Demo Unreal Engine 5 level and it simply does not load and everything is black

Tags: crash, game-engine, game-development, unreal-engine5, unreal

I open the Meerkat Demo level and it simply does not load and everything is black at the bottom and you can see the sky and still see this bird , spot lighting and camera.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlM3B.png)

I expected Level to open normally and see rocks sand mountains and everything else as it should be[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crwfP.jpg)

I've already tried reinstalling Unreal Engine, but that didn't help. I will look for a solution and hopefully I will be able to enjoy all the features of UE5 in the near future!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.